# "Given 2 ints, a and b, return true if one if them is 10 or if their sum is 10." How can I apply real numbers

Tags: java

```
 package cornett1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodeRat {



    public static boolean makes10(int a  , int b) 
    { 
         return (a + b == 10 || a == 10 || b == 10);

        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print(makes10(s.nextInt(),s.nextInt());
        }
}
```

I am using a website called codingbat to do programming exercises and I solved the question
"Given 2 ints, a and b, return true if one of them is 10 or if their sum is 10." How can I apply this program and Input actual numbers.

Comment: have you heard of Scanner api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest option you have is

**java.util.Scanner**

> **Defention**: A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.
>
> 1. **A Scanner breaks its input into tokens
>      using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace**.
> 2. **The  resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types
>      using the various next methods.**

**Why using Scanner API?**

> **1**. A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.
>
> **2**. A scanning operation may block waiting for input.
>
> **3** .A Scanner is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization.

For example:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("the number you entered is " + i);
```

**Explanation**:

you read from console and feed scanner variable which is input and you just want to read int. at the end, you print the read number on the console

Resources

1. [first one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm)
2. [second one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Another option is using BufferedReader API

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as
>   to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.
>   The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The
>   default is large enough for most purposes.

[take a look at this sample for your BufferReader need](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)

**BufferReader vs Scanner**

1. `BufferedReader` has significantly larger buffer memory than Scanner. Use `BufferedReader` if you want to get long strings from a stream, and use `Scanner` if you want to parse specific type of token from a stream.
2. `Scanner` can use tokenize using custom delimiter and parse the stream into primitive types of data, while `BufferedReader` can only read and store String.
3. `BufferedReader` is synchronous while `Scanner` is not. Use `BufferedReader` if you're working with multiple threads.

In your case:

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter two numbers");
    a = input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();
    JOption jp = new JOption();
    jp.makes10(a, b);
}

public boolean makes10(int a, int b) {
    return ((a + b) == 10 || a == 10 || b == 10);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a main method in the class, and pass in two numbers when invoking the program.
In the main method, Use

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(argument 0);
int b = Integer.parseInt(argument 1);
```

Now create a new instance of JOption class and invoke the method 'makes10' in the method with the arguments.

```
JOption opt = new JOption();
boolean answer = opt.makes10(a, b);

System.out.println(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

This tells you how to take arguments form the command line and use those as variables in your program.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.print(makes10(a,b));
}
```

If you want input at runtime, you can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class or the Console class

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print(makes10(s.nextInt(),s.nextInt()));
```

Comment: I added the scanner class, but it is telling me to insert a third ")" at the end. ill repost code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scanner` to get input from a user :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(makes10(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt()));
```